# Parsing json in C# without knowing indexes

Tags: c#, .net, json, mono, json.net

I want to parse this piece of JSON in C# with JSON.NET, but I don't know how to go about it.

Json:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "rgInventory":{
       "967633758":{
          "id":"967633758",
          "classid":"23973033",
          "instanceid":"11040671",
          "amount":"1",
          "pos":1
       },
      "302756826":{
          "id":"302756826",
          "classid":"15",
          "instanceid":"11041143",
          "amount":"1",
          "pos":2
      },...
   }
}
```

Full Json: http://steamcommunity.com/id/jessecar/inventory/json/440/2/?trading=1

I need to get the elements of each "rgInventory" child, but I can't make a class for it because the item names are always changing.

I tried using this piece of code, but I always get an exception.

```
dynamic jsObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

Console.WriteLine("Status: "+jsObject["success"]); //This works fine

foreach(var i in jsObject["rgInventory"]){
    Console.WriteLine("Item ID: "+i["id"]); //This gives an exception
}
```

Exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work.

```
var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach(var child in jObj["rgInventory"].Children())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Item ID: {0}", child.First()["id"]);
}
```

Additionally, using `dynamic` keyword can make your code more readible:

```
dynamic jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
Console.WriteLine("Status: " + jObj.success); 
foreach(var child in jObj.rgInventory.Children())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Item ID: {0}", child.First.id);
}
```