# How to parse dynamic JSON .net newtonsoft

Tags: .net, json, windows-phone-8

I've tried following the example [Parsing json in C# without knowing indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446989/parsing-json-in-c-sharp-without-knowing-indexes). I keep hitting an error though:

> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for ip_addresses

What I am trying to achieve is to parse the following JSON and add each ip address to an ObservableCollection. It's all very well doing it normally if I knew the keys but the IP addresses can be named anything.

Here is the code that I am working on so far and the reason that the IP address has it's own class is because there is a lot more going to be done with it later in the app.:

```
    try
    {
        dynamic jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(e.Result);
        foreach (var child in jObj.ip_addresses.Children())
        {
            ips.Add(new IpAddresses() { ip = child });
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Generic error message");
    }

    public class IpAddresses
    {
        public string ip { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the JSON:

```
{
    "id": "reallysimpleid",
    "label": "server name",
    "ip_addresses": {
    "private0_v4": "100.100.100.100",
    "access_ip0_v4": "100.100.100.100",
    "public0_v6": "1000:1000:7805:0113:9073:8c63:1000:1000",
    "access_ip1_v6": "1000:1000:7805:0113:9073:8c63:1000:1000",
    "public1_v4": "100.100.100.100"
},
    "metadata": null,
    "managed": false,
    "uri": "https://www.awebsite.com",
    "agent_id": null,
    "created_at": 1360960027217,
    "updated_at": 1360960027217
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class should look like this:

```
     public class IpAddresses
     {
     public string private0_v4 { get; set; }
     public string access_ip0_v4 { get; set; }
     public string public0_v6 { get; set; }
     public string access_ip1_v6 { get; set; }
     public string public1_v4 { get; set; }
     }

     public class RootObject
     {
     public string id { get; set; }
     public string label { get; set; }
     public IpAddresses ip_addresses { get; set; }
     public object metadata { get; set; }
     public bool managed { get; set; }
     public string uri { get; set; }
     public object agent_id { get; set; }
     public long created_at { get; set; }
     public long updated_at { get; set; }
     }
```

Your code should be:

```
     jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
```

Comment: please read the question and the last comment ont he last answer

that would work great but sometimes the names of the ip addresses change to random values. It may not always be called public0_v6 for example

Comment: Dang @radoslaf... and Alex if you dont know the name of your elements then you should be using attributes in IPaddresses instead!

Comment: If the names of your elements are going to vary, you should consider using the [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) class instead of dynamic...

Comment: It's not my JSON so it cannot be changed to suit my needs.

Comment: @SandraWalters have you got an example with the expandoobject?

Comment: @AlexBailey - Certainly, take a look at my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631208/deserializing-a-json-object-hierarchy-into-a-hierarchy-of-dictionarystring-obj/13649836#13649836).  It's ideal for situations where the incoming JSON is out of your control and element names are fluid.

Answer (score 0):

The `child` object is probably not what you want, as it is a `JProperty` object; if all you require is actually the string IP Address, then use this:

```
ips.Add(new IpAddresses() { ip = child.Value.ToString() });
```